# jq: Accessing fields with - character in shell script

Tags: json, shell, jq

I am trying to access the field "my-tag" from the following json using jq from a shell script:

json file:

```
{
    "tag": {
        "value": "hello"
    },
    "my-tag": {
        "value": "hello-my-tag"
    }
}
```

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
main()
{
    search="my-tag"
    file="myjson.json"
    value=($(jq ".$search.value" "$file"))
    echo $value
}

main "$@"
```

On executing this script, I get the following error:

```
error: tag is not defined
.-tag.value
^^^
1 compile error
```

How can I extract the field correctly in the shell script?

Comment: `.-tag.value` makes it look like the shell variable `$tag` doesn't contain `my-tag` like you think it does (but rather contains `-tag`). Are you sure about its contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use the associative array notation for arbitrary key strings

```
jq ".[\"$search\"].value" "$file
```

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb, I would strongly suggest not placing shell variables within your filters, and use arguments to pass them in.

```
jq --arg search "$search" '.[$search].value' "$file"
```

Your filter string is an equivalent to a script. You wouldn't want to modify your script every time you wanted to change a value, you would parameterize it.